# Find the min depth of a binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have 2 classes, BSTSet and BSTNode, each class has a minDepth method. Currently my methods are returning the wrong number..

BSTSet

```
 public int minDepth() {
   if(root == null) return -1;
    else return root.minDepth();
}
```

BSTNode

```
 public int minDepth() {
    if(left == null && right == null) return 0;
    if(left != null  && right == null) {return left.height()+ 1; }
    else if(right != null && left == null ){return right.height()+ 1;}
    else{return Math.min(right.height(), left.height()) + 1;}
}
```

I can't understand why, I bit of clarity would be great thanks! also if you need anymore code please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
else{return Math.min(right.height(), left.height()) + 1;}
```

you should be calling minDepth() on right and left nodes rather than height().

Comment: Not sure what the difference between height and min depth are, but it might also apply to the two lines before this as well.